# mysql - does the size of the table have impact on inserting speed?

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a table with auto-increment int with maximum of 255 length as primary key, which I believe is the longest possible. It was silky smooth in the beginning, but now in 1000th row, I notice 1-3 seconds delay when inserting a new row. Will it get worse in the future or is it completely unrelated?

Comment: How many keys (indexs) are there in your table?

Comment: Duplicate of [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507976/does-table-size-affect-insert-performance).

Comment: When your index can no longer be stored in memory, your performance will sharply degrade as the engine will have to write and read from disk.

Comment: Try `show table status from [dbname]` and look for the `Index_length` field to see how big the index is.